# Explaining Why the Zero Conditional Mean Assumption is Important

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation, regression, economics

I am currently relearning econometrics in more depth than I had before. One thing I am trying to make sense of currently is why it is necessary for the assumption of: 
$$E(u\mid x)=E(u) $$
to be true (where $u$ is the error term).

Here is how I have tried to reason through it, although I am not sure if this is a good reasoning on why.

Let's say $u$ is somehow correlated with some variable $y$, which $x$ is also correlated with. In this case, 
$$E(u\mid x) \not= E(u) $$
since for greater $x$ values the expectation of the error would go up or down since it is correlated with $x$ through the $y$ variable. With this being the case, the line of best fit would end up with greater or lesser expected errors as $x$ increases and decreases.

Is this what the zero conditional mean assumption is trying to say, or is there a better reasoning that I'm not hitting on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This assumption means that the error $u$ doesn't vary with $x$ *in expectation*. Often $\mathbb{E}u=0$, so this means that the error is always centered on your prediction.

This is weaker than independence, though, where $\mathbb{E} [f(u)|x]=\mathbb{E}[f(u)]$ for all (measurable) functions $f$.

In particular, if we take $f(u)=(u - \mathbb{E}[u|x])^2=(u-\mathbb{E}u)^2$ it is possible that $\mathbb{E}[f(u)|x] = \operatorname{Var}(u|x)$ can vary with time with this assumption. In a different word: heteroskedasticity.

Comment: In that last line, are you saying that heteroskedasticity can occur even if this assumption is satisfied?

Comment: @M.Damon yes precisely!

Comment: I’m still slightly confused then. Would a violation of this mean something like having more data points end up above the line as the $x$ values increase?

Comment: @M.Damon Yep — since that would mean that the expected error increases. If you think about it another way that’d mean your model was poorly chosen since it doesn’t capture the data trends.

Comment: Alright thank you. I feel like I actually kind of get it now.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that you model the conditional expectation, hence if $\mathbb{E}[u|x]=g(x)$
$$
\mathbb{E}[y|x] = \mathbb{E} [a + b x + u|x]=a+bx+g(x),
$$ 
then $g(x)$ is a part that you should model/approximate. If $g(x) = c$, i.e., a constant, then you can just add it to the intercept, i.e., $y=(a+c)+bx+\epsilon$ and $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon|x]=0$, otherwise you should impose explicit structure on $g(x)$. Hence, the assumption is 
$$
\mathbb{E}[u|x]=\mathbb{E}[u]=0,
$$
means that given $x$, if you discard the disturbance $u$, you have a linear model in the parameters. Your main interest is $\mathbb{E}[u|x]$, as you look at the model given $x$ and not just at the error term itself.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption $E(u\mid x)=0$ is a sufficient condition so that estimators like least squares are unbiased. In general such assumptions are made with an eye towards desirabe properties of the estimators.